# Grammatical expression

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

What is the grammatical name given to this expression:

> with fear and trembling

Comment: Adverbial clause?

Answer (score 1):

In the famous examples, which I assume to be the origin - anciently - of the expression, namely the four occasions of its use in the KJV [1611] the phrase is used adverbially on all four occasions :

> I was with you [...] in fear and trembling, I Corinthians 2:3
>
> [...] with fear and trembling, ye received [...], II Corinthians 7:15
>
> be obedient [...] with fear and trembling, Ephesians 6:5
>
> work out your own salvation, with fear and trembling, Philippians 2:12.

The expression is previously used in [The Wycliffe](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Uzw6AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=fear+and+trembling+wycliffe&source=bl&ots=y4mPsEIMvv&sig=1Ofoh9FoxwVqusfsnxw-0CEWThg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9uvrw6fHXAhWLAsAKHeBLBBIQ6AEISzAE#v=onepage&q=fear%20and%20trembling%20wycliffe&f=false) translation of 1388.

Comment: Have you looked up whether those are all translating the same thing and if so what?

Comment: @tchrist Yes, indeed. φοβοσ, _phobos_ [Strong 5401] is consistently 'fear'; τρομος, _tromos_ [Strong 5156] is consistently 'trembling'.

Answer (score 0):

At base, it's simply a prepositional phrase:

with = preposition
fear = object of preposition 1
and = conjunction
trembling = (gerund) object of preposition 2

It is most likely going to be used adverbially, but I suppose you might be able to figure out a way to use it as an adjective—"Journeys with fear and trembling" or something.

Comment: Specifically, it's a prepositional phrase with a conjoined noun phrase as its object. And _trembling_ is not a gerund in this phrase, but just another noun.

Comment: I agree with your first sentence, but a gerund is "just another noun." The difference between a gerund and a present participle is precisely that a gerund is a noun.

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. Sorry. It's certainly true that gerunds are not ordinary nouns. What I meant to say was that _trembling_ is a noun, and is **not** a gerund. Gerunds are one type of _-ing_ word, but [not all _-ing_ words are gerunds](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html).

Comment: Let's see if I'm understanding you, now. Are you saying that because trembling couldn't take a direct object in this sentence, it is a noun form of "-ing" that is not a gerund, but is simply an example of the number 5: "true noun" or "verbal noun" in the article you linked? If so, I can see the linguistic distinction you are making. Thank you for the very interesting article link.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. There's a lot more variety in structure than people are ever taught about in school (where, in Anglophone schools at least, the details of English syntax and structure are never mentioned -- because the teachers don't know them either). As I used to tell my students, linguistics is the best-kept secret in America.

Comment: Thanks @JohnLawler. Is the -ing participle required to actually have a subject or object to be a gerund, or is it enough that it _could_ have one. For example, is understanding a gerund in "Understanding was important"? Or does it become a gerund only when you say something like "(My) understanding the problem was important"?

Comment: There's always a subject, but it doesn't always occur in the gerund clause. It is either recoverable from the context (_I like swimming laps_ has _I_ as subject of _swimming_ as well as _like_), or else they've got an indefinite subject (_They say that climbing that face is impossible_ has `Indef` as the subject; i.e, the subject is an indefinite pronoun, like _everybody, anybody, somebody,_ etc. which is deleted in context).